# Xamarin: Create layout main content, left drawer and right drawer using Xamarin native and then go Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The issue I need to create left and right side menu without using a plugin in Xamarin forms but right side menu is not supported.

can I create layout contains main content, left and right drawer using xamarin native and use this layout as the master layout in Xamarin forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have both menus, you can use the following:

1. Use a layaout for the main content and add two buttons (one for display right menu, the other for the left).
2. Add a layout after the main for the left menu and set visibility to hide
3. Add the code that when the user tap the button, changes the visibility of the layout created in 2.
4. Repeat for the right menu.

This is a easy way to achieve it. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **slideoverkit**, if you want to with the plugin. This will help you otherwise it will take a lot of time for some perfect solution.